# Как обработать событие в главном потоке при использовании Retfofit

Tags: java, retrofit, foreach, события

Добрый день, у меня есть фрагмент, в него с помощью адаптера помещаются данные, изначально данные пусты и адаптер ничего не выводит, с помощью GET запроса библиотеки RETROFIT получаю json обьект, паршу его и вывожу в адаптер, но загрузка происходит в парралальном потоке, конечно раньше я просто вызывал adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() в onResponse() задания. Но теперь мне нужно загруженные объекты наполнить другими объектами через цикл и другой запрос

```
ApiInterface service = ApiModule.getClient();
Call<List<offerClass>> offerCall = service.getActiveSimpleOrder(1); // указываем id ресторана.
offerCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<offerClass>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<offerClass>> call, Response<List<offerClass>> response) {
        offers.clear(); // Очистить контейнер перед наполнением.
        try {
            offers.addAll(response.body()); // Получили заказы
            Log.i("Call","Request assigned");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ApiInterface service = ApiModule.getClient();
        for(final offerClass offer:offers) // Для каждого заказа ищем статус
        {
              Call<orderStatus> statusCall = service.getOrderStatus(Integer.parseInt(offer.getId()));
              // Для каждого заказа получаем его статус.
              statusCall.enqueue(new Callback<orderStatus>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(Call<orderStatus> call, Response<orderStatus> response) {
                     // если статус получен присваиваем его заказу

                     offer.setStatus(response.body());

                  }
                  @Override
                  public void onFailure(Call<orderStatus> call, Throwable t) {
                  }
        });
```

Как видите загружается основной класс offers, и для каждого offer загружается его статус status через цикл. Как мне обновить адаптер в основном потоке, какое событие и как создать?  когда я буду точно уверен что цикл отработал? потому что данный код вызовет в адаптере nullpointer exception, данные приходят по запросу, но я не уверен что код работает так как я думаю и хочу чтобы он работал.

Было решено разобраться с функционированием RX и типом данных Observable.

```
Отрывок из Rest API interface, сигнатура запросов. 
  @GET("orderStatus/{id}")
  Observable<orderStatus> getOrderStatus(@Path("id") int id);
  @GET("activeSimpleOrder/{id}")
  Observable<List<offerClass>> getActiveSimpleOrder(@Path("id") int id);
```

Отрывок кода из основного потока фрагмента:

```
    Observable<List<offerClass>> offercall =service.getActiveSimpleOrder(1);
    Observable<orderStatus> statusCall = service.getOrderStatus(1);
```

Таким образом мы получаем лист offerClass содержащий объекты каждый со своим id с пустым orderStatus.

И потом получаем orderStatus для "1" id.

А вообще надо получить orderStatus для всего листа . подставляя в функцию id каждого offerClass.getId(). Таким образом получить "наполненный" класс.
и после всего вызвать adapterNotifyDataSetChanged() в основном потоке, тем самым обработав событие.

как я понимаю должен быть создан обьект  (в каком месте кода? в онкрейт фрагмента?)

Observable myObservable

с методом

@Override public void call

в котором скачать данные и заполнить класс offerClass обьектами класса orderStatus и вызвать myObsevable.onCompleted();

Потом создать (где? как?)

```
Subscriber<orderStatus> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<orderStatus>() {
@Override
public void onCompleted() { }
@Override
public void onError(Throwable e) { }
```

и соотвественно когда Observable закончит наполнение, он вызовет onCompleted и "лисенер" или Subscriber вызовется медот onCompleted() в котором то при получении НАПОЛНЕННЫХ классом orderStatus данных мы сможем присвоить их адаптеру adapter.set(List) и сделать adapterNotifyDataSetChanged.

но это только в теории, может кто нибудь написать коротенький скетч наполнения  offerClass классом orderStatus через Object.setStatus(this.orderStatus) и считывания его в Subscriber???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть такой простенький бэкэнд

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    print_r('{"status":"status_' . $_GET['id'] . '"}');
} else {
    print_r('{"orders":[{"order":1},{"order":2},{"order":3},{"order":4},{"order":5}]}');
}
```

Если обратиться без параметров, он отдает список ордеров

```
{"orders":[{"order":1},{"order":2},{"order":3},{"order":4},{"order":5}]}
```

Если с параметром id, то возвращает статус по конкретному ордеру

```
{"status":"status_2"}
```

С помощью http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ на скорую руку делает классы модели

```
public class Orders {
    public List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Order {
    @SerializedName("order") public int id;
    public String status;

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

public class Status {
    public String status;
}
```

Интерфейс API

```
public interface RestApi {
    String URL = "http://server/";
    RestApi api = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build()
            .create(RestApi.class);

    @GET("index.php")
    Observable<Status> getOrderStatus(@Query("id") int id);

    @GET("index.php")
    Observable<Orders> getActiveSimpleOrder();
}
```

Нюанс в том, что информация по статусам всех ордеров запрашивается асинхронно
(Я под JavaSE делал, так как с андроидом мороки много, но там все то же самое)

```
public class Main {
    private static boolean finish = false; //Чтоб основной поток не завершился раньше получения результата, для андроида не нужно

    public static void main(String... args) {
        HashMap<Integer, Order> orders = new HashMap<>(); //тут храним ордера
        PublishSubject<Boolean> subject = PublishSubject.create(); //счетчик

        RestApi.api.getActiveSimpleOrder()
                .map(result -> {
//Взводим счетчик на выполнение print(orders) после того, как отработают все запросы по статусам
//То есть счетчик выполнит свой Action только когда отбросит все сигналы кроме последнего skip(result.orders.size() - 1)
                    subject.skip(result.orders.size() - 1).subscribe(b -> print(orders));
                    return result;
                })
                .flatMap(result -> Observable.from(result.orders))
                .subscribe( order -> {
                            final Integer id = order.id;
                            orders.put(id, order);
                            RestApi.api.getOrderStatus(id)
                                    .subscribe(status -> {
                                        orders.get(id).setStatus(status.status);
//сигнализируем счетчику об отработке запроса по статусу
                                        subject.onNext(true); 
                                    });
                        }
                );
//цикл, чтоб основной поток не закрылся, для android не актуально
        while (!finish) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void print(HashMap<Integer, Order> orders) {
        for (Order order : orders.values()) {
            System.out.format("%d = %s\n", order.id, order.status);
        }
        finish = true;
    }
}
```

Результат работы

```
1 = status_1
2 = status_2
3 = status_3
4 = status_4
5 = status_5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: не могли бы вы обьяснить что делает ваш код. повторюсь мне нужно чтобы основной поток выполнил adapterNotifyDataSetChanged() только после того как я захочу, т.е. после заполнения offers данными, но проблема не в том чтобы заполнить offers данными а в том что каждый обьект offers (offer) заполнился данными с сервера, и вот потом этот раздутый мешок надо сунуть адаптеру, но основной поток не знает когда это сделать и как.

Comment: @user264795 Этот код выполняет offer.setStatus(response.body()); в UI потоке. А вообще, мой вам совет. Раз уж взялись за Retrofit, используйте его с rxJava. Придется в него немного повъезжать, но зато потом жизнь заиграет новыми красками. Например весь приведенный кусок кода легко поместится в однострочник. (ну или строк в 8, если callChain по строкам разбивать)

Comment: почитал про Observable, про RxJava, кое что прояснилось, основная идея в том чтобы с помощью метода GET библиотеки получить обьект Observable, и далее обрабатывать его, действительно RxJAva это то что нужно когда речь заходит о большом количестве REST Запросов, их комбинировании. Я переделал сигнатуры запросов в Api моего класса. теперь они возвращают Observable, у меня осталось несколько вопросов, я обновил вопрос.

Comment: это удивительно и невероятно! я почти ничего не понимаю, вернее что делает почти понятно но как делает это вообще космос, так и что теперь остается в главном потоке подписаться на этот observable? а этот код выполнить в какой нибудь функции при onCreate фрагмента??

Comment: пришлось задать еще один вопрос, т.к. заставить код работать самостоятельно у меня не получилось( про котлин уже посмотрел. оставил в TODO

Comment: хорошо загляните сюда, в мой новый вопрос, заработете еще один ответ, можно в профиле глянуть, ссылки вставлять почему то нельзя.

Comment: @user264795 обновил ответ

Comment: не получается, можем словиться в скайпе? mustang94free логин. Возможно это не по правилам, я в долгу не останусь, мне нужна ваша помощь.