# Как обработать данные с помощью RxJava в Android

Tags: android, retrofit, lambda, rest, rxjava

Стоит задача сделать два типа запросов с помощью REST библиотеки в Android приложении, получить два типа объектов, и наполнить один, другим.

Можно конечно запилить асинк таск и в нем последовательно выполнить все операции. 
А можно попытаться использоваться RXjava но я с ней знаком второй день, и мало что еще понимаю, не говорю уже о лямбда выражениях, статьи на хабре тоже уже для ушедших далеко, почти ничего не понятно.

Кароч.
есть два класса 
 1. offerClass - каждый класс при спарсивании json получает свой id. содержит в себе пустой класс orderStatus который можно получить другим запросом, используя id.
 2. orderStatus - класс содержит информацию, для конкретного id offerClass.

Есть переменная offers = new ArrayList(); которая при onCreate() равна нулю, и отдается адаптеру для построения View.

В методе onCreate() вызывается функция downloadData() которая с помощью RXjava скачивает и наполняет данные, и возвращает адаптеру в главный поток.

Что я хочу сделать:

```
1.выполнить асинхронный запрос getActiveSimpleOrder(1) 
2.по нему получить List<offerClass> и присвоить его offers.
3. наполнить каждый объект offers (offer - статутом, зная id)
for(offerClass offer:offers) // для каждого объекта offers 
{
4. getOrderStatus(offer.getId()) //Получив статус для конкретного объекта.
и далее offer.setStatus(response.body()) // Наполняем объект статусом.
}
5. когда все выполнится передать offers в основной поток и вызвать
6. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().
```

После ответов был сформирован новый код:

В главном методе фрагмента:

```
 public void onStart() { initializeData(); // Получаем данные }
```

Код функции:

```
private void initializeData() {
        int rest_id = 1;
                ApiInterface api = ApiModule.getClient(); 
                api.getActiveSimpleOrder(rest_id) 
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(Observable::from)
                .flatMap(offer -> api.getStatus(offer.getId()) 
                        .doOnNext(offer::setStatus) 
          *******       .map(status -> offer) *******************
                )
                .toList() 
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
                .subscribe(adapter::setOffers); 
    }
```

Код api :

```
public class ApiModule {

    private static ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private static String baseUrl = ""http://85.143.221.39/EatgidServer/";
    public static ApiInterface  getClient() {
        if (apiInterface == null) {

            Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                   .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()) 
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            apiInterface = client.create(ApiInterface.class);

        }
        return apiInterface;
    }
}
```

Строка со звездочками подчеркнута красным: компилятор все равно компилирует. что странно. варнинг такой:
[image: ругань]

Приложение работает с ошибкой:

LogCat:

```
  06-13 19:59:53.954 13429-13429/eatgid.com.restaurant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: eatgid.com.restaurant, PID: 13429
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
                                                                           at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:60)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                                                                        Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: 1465819531027
                                                                           at rx.Observable$27.onError(Observable.java:8139)
                                                                           at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:157)
                                                                           at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:254)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:186)
                                                                           at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
                                                                        Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1465819531027
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:74)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:59)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:41)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216)
                                                                           at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
                                                                           at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
                                                                           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:116)
                                                                           at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
                                                                           at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
                                                                           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:160)
                                                                           at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
                                                                           at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
                                                                           at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
                                                                           at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
                                                                           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:141)
                                                                           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:127)
                                                                           at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                                                                           at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                                                                           at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                                                                           at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                                                                           at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                                                                           at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                                                                           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8314)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:235)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:145)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:368)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:330)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:807)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.slowpath(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:97)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.request(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:73)
                                                                           at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:49)
                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:32)
                                                                           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8314)
                                                                        at rx.internal.op
```

Comment: Вот тут расписал рабочий вариант очень близкий по сути http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532152/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-retfofit/532187#532187

Comment: Подсветка строки со звездочками как ошибки это глюк анализатора в IDE, он с лямбдами к сожалению подглючивает иногда.

Comment: А ошибка работы у вас теперь не в коде, точнее не в логике. У вас несуществующий адрес запрашивается `HttpException: HTTP 400 Bad Request`

Comment: прошу прощеная за эту оплошность, забыл обновить действительно, но ошибка сохранилась, я так понимаю проблема в парсиньи даты, едло в том что статус содержит несколько обьектов типа date которые методами String getDate выдергиваются из Status адаптером.

либо в том что библиотека не может спарсить обьект даты,
можно как то обработать onError чтобы приложение не вылетало, хоть тостер добавить, и в OnComplited плюхнуть что нибудь, как это прописать? нужен субсрибер с оверрайдом сиих методов? если субскрибер это main therad где мне следует переопределить вышеописанные методы?

Comment: для обработки ошибки можно дописать в метод subscribe второй параметр: `.subscribe(adapter::setOffers, throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace());`. Пишу по памяти так что мог название метода printStackTrace не совсем верно написать.

Comment: Вообще если хотите можете мне в скайп написать, а то у нас пошел какой то дебаг через комменты, логин - ikskor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Должно быть как то так:

```
ApiInterface api = ApiModule.getClient(); // создадим только один сервис с апи, не надо дергать getClient() несколько раз
api.getActiveSimpleOrder(1) // запрашиваем список
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // запросы и дальнейшие преобразования будут выполняться в потоке для операций ввода/вывода
    .flatMap(Observable::from) // превращаем список в последовательность что бы работать дальше отдельно с каждым заказом
    .flatMap(offer -> api.getOrderStatus(offer.getId()) // запрашиваем статус
        .doOnNext(offer::setStatus) // записываем полученный статус в объект заказа
        .map(status -> offer) // небольшая хитрость что бы дальше шли объекты заказов а не статусов
    )
    .toList() // преобразуем последовательность обратно в список
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // дальнейшие действия над данными будем производить в главном потоке
    .subscribe(adapter::setOffers); // подписываемся на получение списка инициируя тем самым старт запросов
```

У `adapter` должен быть метод `public void setOffers(List<offerClass> offers)` в котором вы должны записать пришедший список как вам надо и вызвать `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Если синтаксис `Observable::from` вам не знаком то это просто сокращение от `offers -> Observable.from(offers)`, а `adapter::setOffers` соответственно от `offers -> adapter.setOffers(offers)`.

---

> он че сам понял что объект из листа offers это offer? или это должно быть название класса, или это название результата отработки апи как это вообще?

В строчке `.flatMap(Observable::from)` мы говорим что дальше по цепочке пойдет вместо объекта класса `List<offerClass>` объекты из этого списка и соответственно класса `offerClass`. Затем в строчке `.flatMap(offer -> api.getOrderStatus(offer.getId())` мы пишем лямбда функцию которая принимает в качестве параметра класс `offerClass` (компилятор это сам понимает, и мы можем не указывать класс самостоятельно), имя этому параметру мы задаём сами, я обозвал его `offer`. Эта функция будет применена для каждого offer из полученного списка. Далее в теле лямбда функции мы создаём обсервабл запроса статуса (`api.getOrderStatus(offer.getId())`), в следующей строчке (`.doOnNext(offer::setStatus)`) говорим что каждый полученый `orderStatus` мы должны отправить в метод `offer.setStatus()`. Затем строчкой `.map(status -> offer)` мы игнорируем статус класса `orderStatus` так он нам дальше не нужен, и возвращаем в обработку offer класса `offerClass` ибо нам в итоге нужно получить список этих классов. Почему у вас на эту строчку ругается мне не понятно, приведите пожалуйста полное название и сообщение об ошибке.

> что именно мы преобразуем в toList?

`.toList()` это операция обратная `.flatMap(Observable::from)`, то есть эта команда ждет пока обработаются все `offerClass` и собирает их в `List<offerClass>`, на которой мы дальше и подписываемся.

> почему мы выполняем операции Schedulers.io()? это безопасно? есть другие потоки которые можно выбрать?

В RxJava есть следующие варианты планировщиков:

- AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() - для выполнения операций в главном потоке
- Schedulers.io() - для выполнения длительных запросов к ресурсам (сетевые запросы, запросы в базу данных и т.п.) в пуле потоков
- Schedulers.computation() - для вычислительных операций (там например рекомендуют выполнять map оператор, но мы пока не будем излишне усложнять код)

Есть и другие, о них можно подробнее почитать [тут](http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html) в секции RxJava.

> разве нам не нужно сделать Observable::from и бля обьекта status полученного командой api.getOrderStatus(offer.getId())

Не нужно. Мы и так получаем не список а сразу статус по этому обрабатывать по частям нам там нечего.

> при попытке скомпилить ваш код : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable> for method ApiInterface.getActiveSimpleOrder

У вас не подключен CallAdapterFactory необходимый для преобразования Retrofit запроса в Observable. Надо дополнить код:

```
    Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()) // без этого ретрофит не сможет возвращать Observable объекты
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

И если вы ещё не подключали эту библиотеку то подключите её:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:{версия ретрофита}'
```

Comment: он че сам понял что обьект из листа offers это offer? или это должно быть название класса, или это название результата отработки апи как это вообще?

почему мы выполняем операции Schedulers.io()? это безопасно? есть другие потоки которые можно выбрать? можно ли создать свой поток?

что именно мы преобразуем в toList? 
1. метод для адаптера запилил.
2. жалуется на строку .map(status -> offer) что то там про ловер и апер боундс.

Comment: разве нам не нужно сделать Observable::from и бля обьекта status полученного командой   api.getOrderStatus(offer.getId())

Comment: что за хитрость .map(status -> offer)  что делает эта команда на самом деле?  почему к примеру не завести счетчик статусов равный заказы.размер и не отреагировать когда будет получен последний?

Comment: при попытке скомпилить ваш код :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable<java.util.List<eatgid.com.restaurant.adapter.offerClass>>
                                                                           for method ApiInterface.getActiveSimpleOrder

Comment: Дописал в ответ ответы)

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ. это было круто и эпично. многое стало понятно. я обновил вопрос с новыми данными

Comment: 1. ConversionFactory подключена к  api
2. Библиотека была уже поключена

Comment: Косяк с адресом исправлен)